# The limit of an integral over a ball when the radius of the ball goes to zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $D(a,r)$ be an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ ($ k\geq1 $). We know that if $f$ is a continuous function at $a$, then 
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{V_{r}}\int_{D(a,r)}f(t)dt=f(a),$$ where $V_{r}$ is the measure of the ball.
Does this hold if $f$ is only locally integrable? How to prove it?

Comment: When $k=1$, it seems wrong!  For example $\lim_{t\to 0}\int^{a+r}_{a-r}f(t)dt=0$.But $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int^{a+r}_{a-r}f(t)dt}{2r}=f(a).$

Comment: You need to normalize the integral, i.e. divide by the volume of the ball you integrate over. Everything is local, you work in a neighbourhood of $a$.

Comment: Thanks Hayk. You are right. I did.

Comment: Mean value theorems for definite integrals works for your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is locally integrable then the limit is $f(a)$ for almost all points $a$. This is immediate from Lebesgue's Theorem. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point

Answer (score 2):

No. Take $k=1$ and $f=1_{\mathbb Q}$, the char. function of $ \mathbb Q$. For $a=0$ we have $\int_{D(a,r)}f(t)dt=0$, but $f(a)=1$.

Comment: I think it should be $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\int_{D(a,r)}f(t)dt}{Vol(D(a,r))}=f(a).$

Comment: Measure of the ball is the same as the volume.